# Get the nodevalue of the immediate node using php domdocument xpath query

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I am trying to get the immediate node value. for example

```
<font>..something not related to us......</font>
<font>..something not related to us......</font>
<font><br>Name : </font>
<font>foo</font>
<font>Company :</font>
<font>bar</font>
<font>..something not related to us......</font>
<font>..something not related to us......</font>
```

Here, first i need to find the nodeValue `Name`. If the node value is Name, then I need to save the `foo` for that name.

if the nodeValue is Company, then I need the nodeValue `bar` for the Company.

For this, I have written my code like this

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//font");
foreach($nodes as $node){
            if($node->nodeValue = 'Name :')
                echo $node->nextSibling->nodeValue;
        }
```

Please help me in getting it.  I need to find the next sibling from the current font tag.

Thanks in advance!

This is my complete code --

```
$content = "<font>..something not related to us......</font>
<font>..something not related to us......</font>
<font>Name : </font>
<font>foo</font>
<font>Company :</font>
<font>bar</font>
<font>..something not related to us......</font>
<font>..something not related to us......</font>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($content); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//font[.='Name :']/following-sibling::font[1]/text()");
print_r($nodes);
$name = $nodes[0]->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//font[.='Name : ']/following-sibling::font[1]/text()");
$name = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes

Comment: As a next step, I tried like this to get the next node value `foreach($nodes as $node){
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}` didnt worked for me. Help me how to get the value `foo`

Comment: getting an error : `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array`
if i print_r($nodes);, i am getting 
`DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 0
)`

Comment: I have added the complete code in the question. please check once.

Comment: My bad, I corrected my answer. Beware of the spaces inside the text content of your font element; the string in the predicat [.='Name : '] of the xpath expression must be exactly the same as in your XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...
I have faced the same problem ..
I found solution with the below code . May be it will work for you.

```
foreach($nodes as $node){
    if($node->nodeValue = 'Name :'){
        $nextNode = $node->nextSibling;
        while($nextNode->nodeType == 3){
        $nextNode = $nextNode->nextSibling;
        }
        echo $nextNode->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Here nodeType==3 is some null value between nodes which need to skip.